# Steroid for IBD banned by WADA?

Tags: doping

I have IBD (inflammatory bowel disease), and so my colon as well as cecum get inflamed, and to keep me functional, my doctor has advised me to take prednisolone steroid to reduce swelling of my intestine and cecum. Also, I am on some NSAIDs (Nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drug).

Are these against WADA rules? Will I be banned from WADA-approved sports events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to your governing body, not the Internet. They will be able to give you *accurate* advice as to exactly what is and isn't a prohibited substance and the possibility of you obtaining a therapeutic use exemption (TUE).

Answer (score 2):

It **is** on the WADA [prohibited list](https://www.wada-ama.org/en/content/what-is-prohibited/prohibited-in-competition/glucocorticoids) as being prohibited "in competition", that doesn't mean you couldn't get a Theraputic Use Exemption (TUE) for it. TUE's for corticosteriods used to treat IBD are definitely a thing.

In general terms there's 4 criteria which must all be met for a TUE:

> 1. The athlete would experience significant health problems without taking the prohibited
>    substance or method;
> 2. The therapeutic use of the substance would not produce significant enhancement of
>    performance;
> 3. There is no reasonable therapeutic alternative to the use of the otherwise prohibited
>    substance or method;
> 4. The requirement to use that substance or method is not due to the prior use of the
>    substance or method without a TUE, which was prohibited at the time of use.

You don't submit a request for a TUE to WADA yourself - it's done through which ever Anti-Doping Organisation (ADO) that governs your region/sport. Although your first port of call (as @Philip Kendall says) should probably be the appropriate governing body for the sport